# Дать доступ к папке по PUT и GET, к файлам определённого типа

Tags: put, get

Мне нужно дать доступ к папке, в пределах сервера Apache, по PUT и GET, к файлам определённого типа. Подскажите — как это прописать в htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Если верить документации, то ограничивать доступ по методам запросов кроме PUT, GET можно таким образом:

```
<Limit PUT GET>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from All
</Limit>
```

Т.е., мы разрешили запросы методами PUT, GET, все остальные запретили.

Для ограничения доступа к файлам используется директива <Files>. Полагаю, директива Limit может быть вложенной в директиву Files. Увы, это догадка, т.к.. проверить в настоящий момент негде.

Answer (score 0):

**Для Apache это можно сделать следующим образом**

В файле конфигурации

```
Apache Group\Apache\conf\httpd.conf
```

сразу после описания

```
DocumentRoot "путь к корневому каталогу вашего сайта"
```

добавить следующий код:

```
<Directory />
 Options -Indexes
 AllowOverride All
 Allow from all
 <Limit GET PUT>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Limit>
 <LimitExcept GET PUT>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
 </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```